# How to raw copy an HDD to another one

Tags: hard-drive, clone, clonezilla, copy

I need to backup an HDD in raw mode. I want to backup all data, partition tables, boot and so on.
I have tried Clonezilla but it fails because of a dirty bit on a NTFS volume.

I woruld like to migrate everything to a new bigger disk, and then start working on data recovery. This is why I need a raw copy, and Clonezilla seems to be not suitable, as far as I saw, it checks the NTFS dirty bit.

I'm using Windows, but I can also start a live-cd like Clonezilla.

Comment: ntfsfix does not work? With linux / Unix like disk to disk - raw copy `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`

Answer (score 2):

I present you two options:

**Clonezilla**:
If you use Clonezilla you could set the option *-q1* (in expert mode) and it will use dd to make the copy sector-by-sector. If your source disk has bad sectors you should also set the option *-rescue* to ignore bad sectors.

**OSFClone:**
OSFClone is a specifc tool (bootable) to make a forensic copy of a disk, exact raw.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to run the clone (disk to local disk clone) with the -sfsck option.   This bypasses the checks if the source is OK and just tries to copy everything without checking.

If that doesn't work (too many read-errors) get a GPartED Live USB. This contains (among other things) also the command-line utility `ddrescue` which is specialized in copying from a bad disk.

Comment: This, plus _Remove hibernation and pagefile_ must be disabled, plus dd should be used rather than partclone/ntfsclone, plus probably a bunch of other options. It's probably better to use ddrescue right away at this point.

Comment: @gronostaj I agree. Under no circumstances the source should be changed or the data modified while making the copy. ddrescue is the beter tool.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a data recovery issue there is no shortcut other than duplicating the total drive.

Use ddrescue, a free and open source tool from the GNU foundation. It is contained in many live Linux distributions like in GParted where the CD ISO is only 300-400MB.

Do not confound ddrescue with dd_rescue from Kurt Garloff. dd_rescue has a different command syntax!

The regular dd command in Linux does not handle bad sectors as smart as ddrescue.

I am not aware of tools in the Windows world that have dedicated strategies to duplicate drives fast despite of the existence of bad sectors.